# Save UIImage to documents - need two files?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, save, nsdocumentdirectory

Simple question that I'm asking just as much for myself as for anyone who might stumble upon this at a later date: when saving a UIImage to the documents directory, must I save two versions, one @2x and one for non-retina displays? If so, is it correct to assume that the system would apply the same commands as it does with bundled images and know to use the correct file for each device?

Thanks!

Comment: System will automatically detect which version it should use.

Comment: So, then that's a yes to my first question, too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [`imageNamed:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed%3a) class method from the `UIImage` class does this 'trick' for you.

But since you won't be using the method, but something like [`imageFromContentsOfFile:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithContentsOfFile%3a)
and you're opening a file DIRECTLY and not through a helper method, you should do the @2x trick yourself (extending the `UIImage` class and create something similar would do the trick)